# Using ReorderableListView to show a list of textfields which loose focus immediately after I tap on textfield

Tags: dart, flutter

I am new to Flutter, I code two pages, page A and page B. I use ReorderableListView to show a list of textfields in widget B. When I navigate to page B from page A, the textfields have lost focus immediately after I tap on textfield. Can someone help?

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: TapClass(),
    ));

class TapClass extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: FlatButton(
        child: Text('click me'),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context)
              .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage()));
        },
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ReorderableListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          key: ValueKey('key'),
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'type in'),
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
      onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {},
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have only one child in the ReorderaleListView . You should have more than one child in it and allot all of them different keys. Hope this will  help you.

Comment: thanks, I have try, but it doesn't work, It is some wrong with flutter when run this code with iphone simulator, android is fine

Comment: you're welcome . Okay then you should file an issue on Github .